# Cloud Storage for Firebase: How to recover a pdf

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a pdf stored in Cloud Storage and I'm trying to take this file to send it through email.

I'm trying to recover it but I receive back an error about access deniend:

> Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not
> have permission to access

My code:

```
 const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
 var forestRef = storageRef.child('/uploads/' + offerId + '/' + offerId + '.pdf');

 forestRef.getDownloadURL()
      .then(function (url) {
        console.log("url ", url)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function (event) {
          var blob = xhr.response;
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
      })
```

I think that the problem should be that I'm not using the access token but I don't know how to recover it. ( I have tried to use also the getMetadata, but the result is the same)

Edit:

I have also the url with token

Comment: Do you have specific security rules for Cloud Storage?

Comment: thank you for answer :) the only rule is:       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

Comment: if the user trying to access the file is not authenticated or is logged out they cannot access the file

Answer (score 0):

The files in firebase storage follow a specific url format. use the following format. The url generated from `getDownloadURL()` will have token associated with it causing the link to expire after few days.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<PROJECT-NAME>.appspot.com/o/<PATH>%2F<TOFILE>?alt=media
```

So your url string for `/uploads/${offerId}/${offerId}.pdf` will be :

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<PROJECT-NAME>.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F${offerId}%2F${offerId}.pdf?alt=media
```

Thus by string manipulations you can create the file urls.

Comment: Ty for answer, I have edited my url using directly the one with the token and the right url format as you suggest. I'm using the same user that can access to cloud storage but I receive 403 access denied

Comment: change the security rules

Answer (score 0):

While download URLs provide public, read-only access to files in Cloud Storage for Firebase, calling `getDownloadURL` to *generate* such a URL requires that you have `read` permission on that file.

The error message indicates that the code does not meet your security rules, i.e. that there is no user signed in when you run this code.

If that is not what you expect, I recommend checking that right before you call the Storage API:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var forestRef = storageRef.child('/uploads/' + offerId + '/' + offerId + '.pdf');

if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) throw new "No user signed in, can't get download URL";

forestRef.getDownloadURL()
...
```